# Dynamically select WinJS.Binding.Template (Not ItemTemplate)

Tags: windows-phone-8, binding, winjs

Is there a way to bind value to winControl.template?
I have an hierarchical data structure with 2 or 3 levels.
I would like to have different template for the leafs and the nodes. 
I tried something like this:

```
<ul id="categoriesL1Template" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
  <li>
    <h3 data-win-bind="textContent: name"></h3>
    <ul data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater"
        data-win-bind="winControl.data: subList;
                       winControl.template: template"></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the template in the object is:

```
template: document.getElementById('nodeTemplate').winControl
```

or

```
template: document.getElementById('leafTemplate').winControl
```

But I get JavaScript runtime error: Circular reference in value argument not supported

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of how you can use nested `Repeater`s with `Binding.Template`s and inline templates with a Repeater:

JS

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("Data", {
    list: new WinJS.Binding.List([{
        text: 'one',
        sublist: new WinJS.Binding.List([{
            text: 'sub: one'
        },
        {
            text: 'sub: two'
        }])
    },
    {
        text: 'two',
        sublist: new WinJS.Binding.List([{
            text: 'sub: one'
        },
        {
            text: 'sub: two'
        }])
    }])
});


WinJS.Application.onready = function () {
    WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
    });
};

WinJS.Application.start();
```

HTML

```
<h2>Repeater with inline template with nested Repeater: </h2>
<ul data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater" data-win-options="{data: Data.list}">
    <li>
        <span data-win-bind="textContent: text"></span>
        <span> sub list: </span>
        <ul data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater"
            data-win-bind="winControl.data: sublist">
            <li data-win-bind="textContent: text"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<h2>Repeater with WinJS.Binding.Template with nested Repeater</h2>
<div class="nested" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <li data-win-bind="textContent: text"></li>
</div>
<div class="template" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <li>
        <span data-win-bind="textContent: text"></span>
        <span> sub list: </span>
        <ul data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater"
            data-win-options="{template: select('.nested')}"
            data-win-bind="winControl.data: sublist">
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
<ul data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater"
    data-win-options="{data: Data.list, template: select('.template')}">
</ul>
```

I tend to use the declarative `select()` helper for assigning `Binding.Template`s if they are declaratively defined. Another thing is that I'm assigning the template in the options and not through binding.

In terms of the issue that you are seeing, it might be something in your data structure: [Circular reference in value argument not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836474(v=vs.94).aspx).

Also you can look at the [Repeater sample on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HTML-Repeater-control-da22d278) it has a nested example as well.